# Is px a good unit to use in css?

Tags: css

When styling a website we have to deal with screen sizes and we normally size elements using px unit. I use bootstrap and there as well we have media queries to control at what screen size we should display or hide elements. One example is this

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
  }
```

Now my doubt is whether px is a good unit to use. Here is my reasoning. Ideally we would like the website to look good on all devices of different sizes from small screen mobile phones to large desktops. The resolutions vary in all these devices and so will the pixel size. Here is my main concern. When we have varying pixel size then it doesn't make a lot of sense to use px as unit since we don't know how much that will scale the elements by. So, I appreciate any help in understanding better how to deal with the px unit when pixel sizes vary across devices.

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because it is about CSS programming which is off-topic on Pro Webmasters. It is more ideal for Stack Overflow, however this question has been asked many times in various forms on SO therefore duplicate.

Comment: Please visit Stack Overflow and search through the dozens of questions about EM, PX and REM font-sizing... i.e [Why EM instead of PX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px), [difference between PX and EM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333076/difference-between-px-and-em), [Media Queries PX vs EM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686099/media-queries-px-vs-em-vs-rem) and so forth.